# Display only shows part of what ought to be displayed

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I connected a TV screen to my laptop via HDMI. I connected other displays before, although I had to use an adapter form HDMI to DVI or VGA for all of them and everything worked as it should.

However, with this TV screen, there seems to be a problem.

My laptop has a 4 K screen which I scale down to 1080 p in the display settings. My TV screen's resolution is 1080 p.

[image: Screenshot]

This screenshot looks exactly the way it should with the left half being what my laptop's screen ought to be showing (which it does) and the right half being what my TV screen ought to be showing (which it doesn't).

[image: Photo of laptop screen]

My laptop screen shows exactly what it should, too. You wan see the system tray, for example.

[image: Photo of TV screen]

However, the system tray isn't shown on my TV screen.

Furthermore, the lower part of the screen isn't shown either. I placed the lower calculator so that only its window border is shown on the TV screen, however, there is more than that shown on my laptop's screen.

The problem isn't limited to the vertical axis. As you can see, I placed the upper calculator so that the buttons of the left-most number row are displayed on the laptop screen. The middle and right row should be shown on the TV screen. But as you can see on the photo, most of the middle row isn't shown at all.

I don't think it's Ubuntu's fault because the screenshot looks fine and I connected several screen to my laptop in the past and this didn't happen. My guess is that it's Samsung's (the manufacturer of the TV screen) fault with the display having fewer pixels than it should. The display settings show the advertised resolution:

[image: Display settings]

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu to ignore the outer-most 25 pixels to each border and just treat it like it was a 1870x1030 px screen? I don't care about the screen having the exact same resolution that much, it's just that it's really hard to use both displays if part of the image is missing – particularly if it's such an important area as the system bar where quick settings and the menus of maximized windows are.

**Edit:** Things just got more confusing.

[image: 20x20 px boxes (software side)]

These boxes ought to be exactly 20 px wide and tall. However, they appear to be of different sizes when shown on the TV screen. I counted that the white box is 21 px wide and 22 px tall and the black box is 21 px wide and 20.6 px tall.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by yet another reason to hate TV called "overscan". [Overscan](http://www.howtogeek.com/252193/hdtv-overscan-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-probably-turn-it-off/) stretches the image out a bit.

I was able to turn it off by choosing "Bildanpassung" as the image mode in the TV's image settings. It was set to "16:9" by default.

[image]

"Bildanpassung" is German and roughly translates to "image adaptation". Really, I don't see how this how this makes sense. I just tried every option, hoping that one works out for me. This one (and only this one) does. Plus, the image is much sharper, now.

16:9 should be the default but it should mean that the display shows every pixel as the HDMI signal tells it to. Image adaptation should mean that the image is adapted to conform with the old overscan. If you face the same problem, just try out every image setting of your screen first.